java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unexpected default trust managers in OkHttp3 and Retfrofit when minifyEnabled
I'm facing an issue when using OkHttp3 with minifyEnabled (R8) in my Android app. With R8 enabled, I encounter the following runtime error:
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unexpected default trust managers: [android.security.net.config.RootTrustManager@9e26a00]
    at okhttp3.internal.platform.Platform.platformTrustManager(Platform.kt:82)
    at okhttp3.OkHttpClient.<init>(OkHttpClient.kt:237)
    at okhttp3.OkHttpClient.<init>(OkHttpClient.kt:222)
    at retrofit2.Retrofit$Builder.build(Retrofit.java:628)

Here’s a simplified version of my code:
OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
    .build();
Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
    .client(client)
    .build();


I included the official ProGuard rules for Retrofit and OkHttp, but they’re unnecessary since I’m using R8 for optimization.

Well, I just needed to waste my time and write the question, so suddenly fix it, great.
Add these lines to proguard-rules.pro:
-keep class javax.net.ssl.** { *; }
-keep class android.security.net.config.** { *; }


I am somewhat surprised that the rules you mention made a difference. First of all -keep class javax.net.ssl.** { *; } should not be needed, as these classes are part of the runtime not the program. For the other one -keep class android.security.net.config.** { *; }, do you know from where you get a dependency with classes in the android.security.net.config namespace?

I don't know why it works or which one of the rules fixes my problem, but I get a crash when building the Hilt instance without them
